# Testing a custom react hook that uses another custom hook

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I'm struggling with a test for a custom react hook.

I have two custom hooks: the first one returns the size of my window:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

export const useWindowSize = () => {
  const [windowSize, setWindowSize] = useState({
    width: undefined,
    height: undefined,
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleResize = () => {
      setWindowSize({
        width: window.innerWidth,
        height: window.innerHeight,
      });
    };

    window.addEventListener('resize', handleResize);

    handleResize();

    return () => window.removeEventListener('resize', handleResize);
  }, []);
  return windowSize;
};
```

The second one returns an object to check whether or not I should expand my sidebar

```
import { useMemo } from 'react';
import { SIDEBAR_BREAKPOINT, SIDEBAR_WIDTH, SIDEBAR_WIDTH_EXPANDED } from 'config';
import { useWindowSize } from 'hooks';

export const useSidebarWidth = (): { sidebarWidth: string; isExpanded: boolean } => {
  const { width } = useWindowSize();

  const isExpanded = useMemo(() => {
    if (width < SIDEBAR_BREAKPOINT) {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }, [width]);

  return {
    sidebarWidth: isExpanded ? SIDEBAR_WIDTH_EXPANDED : SIDEBAR_WIDTH,
    isExpanded,
  };
};
```

Now, when trying to test it, I'm stuck between a rock and a hard place:

```
import { renderHook } from '@testing-library/react-hooks';
import { useSidebarWidth } from 'hooks';

describe('useSidebarWidth', () => {
  it('should return 72px as sidebarWidth when width is less than 1440px', () => {
    const { result } = renderHook(() => useSidebarWidth());
    expect(result.current.sidebarWidth).toBe('72px');
  });

  it('should return 248px as sidebarWidth when width is more than 1440px', () => {
    const { result } = renderHook(() => useSidebarWidth());
    expect(result.current.sidebarWidth).toBe('248px');
  });
});
```

In this test, I have two issues: if I run it as is, obviously, the second test will fail (as I didn't change anything regarding my window size). So I figured I'd have to mock the result of my first hook. I added this atop of my test file:

```
let windowWidth = 700;
jest.mock('hooks', () => ({
  useWindowSize: jest.fn(() => ({ width: windowWidth })),
}));
```

And added this in my second test:

```
windowWidth = 1500;
```

But, when using this, it raises the following error:

```
TypeError: (0 , _hooks.useSidebarWidth) is not a function
```

How can I get the best of both world and mock my window size to make sure that both test run smoothly ?

Answer (score 0):

hello man i think your problem is with mocking the hooks file which contains both hooks and you only returned `useWindowSize`.
so instead u should mock `useSidebarWidth` too :

```
let windowWidth = 700;
jest.mock('hooks', () => ({
  useWindowSize: jest.fn(() => ({ width: windowWidth })),
  useSidebarWidth: jest.fn(() => ({sidebarWidth: "72px",isExpanded:true})),
}));
```

or you can use `requireActual` if you don't want to mock useSideBar like this :

```
let windowWidth = 700;
jest.mock('hooks', () => ({
    __esModules: true,
  ...jest.requireActual('hooks')
  useWindowSize: jest.fn(() => ({ width: windowWidth })),
}));
```